# Recursive walk through a JSON file extracting SELECTED strings

Tags: python, json, string, recursion

I need to recursively walk through a JSON files (post responses from an API), extracting the strings that have ["text"] as a key `{"text":"this is a string"}`

I need to start to parse from the source that has the oldest date in metadata, extract the strings from that source and then move to the 2nd oldest source and so on. JSON file could be badly nested and the level where the strings are can change from time to time.

Problem:
There are many keys called ["text"] and I don't need all of them, I need ONLY the ones having values as string. Better, the "text":"string" I need are ALWAYS in the same object {} of a `"type":"sentence"`. See image.

What I am asking

Modify the 2nd code below in order to recursively walk the file and extract ONLY the ["text"] values when they are in the same object {} together with "type":"sentence".

Below a snippet of JSON file (in green the text I need and the medatada, in red the ones I don't need to extract):

[image: screenshot of contents of JSON file]

Link to full JSON sample: http://pastebin.com/0NS5BiDk

What I have done so far:

1) The easy way: transform the json file in string and search for content between the double quotes ("") because in all json post responses the "strings" I need are the only ones that come between double quotes. However this option prevent me to order the resources previously, therefore  is not good enough.

```
r1 = s.post(url2, data=payload1)
j = str(r1.json())

sentences_list = (re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"', j))

numentries = 0
for sentences in sentences_list:
    numentries += 1
    print(sentences)
    print(numentries)
```

2) Smarter way: recursively walk trough a JSON file and extract the ["text"] values

```
def get_all(myjson, key):
    if type(myjson) is dict:
        for jsonkey in (myjson):
            if type(myjson[jsonkey]) in (list, dict):
                get_all(myjson[jsonkey], key)
            elif jsonkey == key:
                print (myjson[jsonkey])
    elif type(myjson) is list:
        for item in myjson:
            if type(item) in (list, dict):
                get_all(item, key)

print(get_all(r1.json(), "text"))
```

It extracts all the values that have ["text"] as Key. Unfortunately in the file there are other stuff (that I don't need) that has ["text"] as Key. Therefore it returns text that I don't need.

Please advise.

**UPDATE**

I have written 2 codes to sort the list of objects by a certain key. The 1st one sorts by the 'text' of the xml. The 2nd one by 'Comprising period from' value.

The 1st one works, but a few of the XMLs, even if they are higher in number, actually have documents inside older than I expected.

For the 2nd code the format of 'Comprising period from' is not consistent and sometimes the value is not present at all. The second one also gives me an error, but I cannot figure out why - `string indices must be integers`.

```
# 1st code (it works but not ideal)

j=r1.json()

list = []
for row in j["tree"]["children"][0]["children"]:
    list.append(row)

newlist = sorted(list, key=lambda k: k['text'][-9:])
print(newlist)

# 2nd code I need something to expect missing values and to solve the
# list index error
list = []
for row in j["tree"]["children"][0]["children"]:
    list.append(row)

def date(key):
    return dparser.parse((' '.join(key.split(' ')[-3:])),fuzzy=True)

def order(list_to_order):
    try:
        return sorted(list_to_order,
                      key=lambda k: k[date(["metadata"][0]["value"])])
    except ValueError:
        return 0

print(order(list))
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample of JSON to be parsed as text — just a screenshot isn't enough.

Comment: @martineau, is it not enough the image I have already loaded? I am not sure I understand your request, sorry. please explain. btw I use python 3.5

Comment: @martineau, how can I load the entire JSON file?

Comment: If someone wants test their code, some sample input will be needed. Folks don't want to have to try making their own. The entire JSON isn't needed, just enough to show the nesting you mention. Alternatively, you could post a link to it the whole thing somewhere like pastebin.

Comment: I have added a full JSON sample link

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "full JSON" because I can't `json.load()` the linked data after downloading it into a local file. In order to do what you want, the structure of the data has to be known in order to select the strings you want. I don't think something completely generic like the recursive routine you posted is going to work.

Comment: @martineau, you cannot json.load() as that file was already transformed to  json by r1.json function of python 3.x requests library. I have now amended the link with the text version. I think now you are able to load it in json. I saw 1 hour ago a comment of a guy now removed that was promising. I hope he can post back

Comment: Yes, that's better, I can now `load()` it without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want, as far as selecting the right strings. I also changed the way type-checking was done to use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=isinstance#isinstance), which is considered a better way to do it because it supports object-oriented polymorphism.

```
import json
_NUL = object()  # unique value guaranteed to never be in JSON data

def get_all(myjson, kind, key):
    """ Recursively find all the values of key in all the dictionaries in myjson
        with a "type" key equal to kind.
    """
    if isinstance(myjson, dict):
        key_value = myjson.get(key, _NUL)  # _NUL if key not present
        if key_value is not _NUL and myjson.get("type") == kind:
            yield key_value
        for jsonkey in myjson:
            jsonvalue = myjson[jsonkey]
            for v in get_all(jsonvalue, kind, key):  # recursive
                yield v
    elif isinstance(myjson, list):
        for item in myjson:
            for v in get_all(item, kind, key):  # recursive
                yield v    

with open('json_sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

numentries = 0
for text in get_all(data, "sentence", "text"):
    print(text)
    numentries += 1

print('\nNumber of "text" entries found: {}'.format(numentries))
```

Comment: thanks it works. can you advise how to check the numentries? there are a couple of conditional loops and no sure where place numentries +=1

Comment: Thanks it works.

1. can you advise how to check the numentries? there are a couple of conditional loops and I am no sure where I have place "numentries +=1"

2. I still need to order the resources before extracting the "text". How I can do it? I studied the JSON file and I found out that the 'resourceType': 'XML', 'text': 'S5CV0280P0.xml' can give me this order. I mean ideally your code should parse the "text" before on 0280 and then 0281. On the original JSON file the .xml are not in order

Comment: I've modified my answer to determine the number of entries without counting each one as it's encountered — it just saves each one in a list and uses the length of that list at the end to determine `numentries`.

Comment: To do the sorting based on date, you're going to need to use the dates in the "Comprising period from" metadata in each "resourceType" dict/object encountered, convert that to a `datetime` and use that as the sorting criteria (aka sort key).

Comment: I've answered the main question you asked about recursively getting the selected strings and feel you should accept my answer — even if it doesn't do all the other processing you apparently would also like to do.

Comment: Sounds like to get the texts in the order you want, the list of dict/objects under the nested `"children"` entry needs to be sorted first. Not sure by what criteria though — XML filename? After doing that the `get_all()` function in my answer will return them in that order.

Comment: 1. the amended code works fine sometimes, other times I can see the stdout appear in the eclipse console and immediately disappear, not sure why? When your 1st code it's fine all the time.

2. for the sort key part, how I can extract (28th july, 1933) by ('metadata': [{'name': 'Comprising period from', 'value': 'monday, 3rd july, to friday, 28th july, 1933'}), and the order the sentences by it? I need to link all the sentences to this value and once ordered them, removed this value form them? it seems complicated.

Comment: ordering for XML filename as said above it's seems correct. not sure how to sort a json dict/objects though. ps. you were great help, thanks so much. not sure how to accept your answer. when I gave you votes it says I have to reach 15 reputations first

Comment: My 1st code just printed each string. The new code puts each on into a list and the prints the whole list at the end. When you print a list of strings, it prints the _representation_ of the string, which is different than the string itself. Maybe something in that format happens to be a console escape sequence. The part you want is the end of the string at `data["tree"]["children"][0]["children"][0]["metadata"][0]["value"]`. The `[0]`s are list indices. You'll need to extract that portion and parse it in order to convert it into a computer value (`datetime`) that could used for sorting. cont..

Comment: @marineau, I have added 2 codes to sort by key and I need some advice. If you published again your 1st code I will accept your answer. Your second code get a console escape sometimes

Comment: I can revert my answer back to the 1st code, but there's actually a third version of the code in my answer now which should avoid the console escape problem _and_ count the numentries — have you tried it? If you want advice on the updated code, I think you should ask a new question.

Comment: your 3rd code is working. However once I sort the list of dictionaries your code not accept a list of dictionaries. I have tried to json.dumps the list in order to extract only the dictionaries but is not working. You probably can give me advice on steps below. cont..

Comment: ... 1) I got the post response (r) and I want it on text  as I need to remove with regex some xml character so r.text  2) Once cleaned I load  j = json.loads(r1.text_clean) and I sort json file by xml numbers or (datetime) - it give me a list of dictionaries that not work on your 3rd code. how I can trasform the list of dictionaries in oder to work in your file? Do I need to iterate again?

Comment: You shouldn't need to transform the list of dictionaries as long as it is JSON-like. The function in this 3rd code is a generator, which means you will need to iterate over the multiple values it yields for every different chunk of JSON data you pass to it.

Comment: It works. I will post another question for the update codes

Comment: what is the function of _NUL = object()?

Comment: It creates a (private) unique object and is the value the `myjson.get(key, _NUL)` call will return when a key is not present. Something needs to be returned to indicate when this happens, but it needs to be a unique value that could never be present in the input from the JSON file — so the code creates one to use.

Comment: P.S. You can move the `_NUL = object()` inside the `get_all()` function if you wished — since that's the only place it's used.

Comment: "Recursively find all the values of key" - is that script really recursive? the function not seems re-call itself. I mean it is correct say code is a recursive walk or more simply an iteration?

Comment: `get_all()` clearly makes calls to itself—so yes, it operates recursively.